# how to send email to particular folder instead of inbox using SMTP c#

Tags: c#, smtp, smtpclient

how to specify folder path in the below code instead of default inbox folder.
how to send email to particular folder instead of inbox using SMTP c#

```
static string smtpAddress = "smtp.gmail.com";
static int portNumber = 587;
static bool enableSSL = true;
static string emailFromAddress = "xxxxx"; //Sender Email Address  
static string password = "xxxxxxx"; //Sender Password  
static string emailToAddress = "xxxx@yyy.vom"; //Receiver Email Address  
static string subject = "Hello";
static string body = "Hello, This is Email sending test using gmail.";

public static void SendEmail()
{
    using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
    {
        mail.From = new MailAddress(emailFromAddress);
        mail.To.Add(emailToAddress);
        mail.Subject = subject;
        mail.Body = body;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        //mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("D:\\TestFile.txt"));//--Uncomment this to send any attachment  
        using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(smtpAddress, portNumber))
        {
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(emailFromAddress, password);
            smtp.EnableSsl = enableSSL;
            smtp.Send(mail);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't. How the recipient organizes his inbox is completely up to them.

Answer (score 0):

The SMTP protocol does not provide a way to send a message to a particular folder for any recipient.